# Python: D'Hondt method with two lists

Tags: python

i have a problem with an Python exercise with D'Hondt method. My code works if i try to run the function "mandatos" with a single list for position **t**, but when i try to do the same thing with two list, for position **n** and position **t**, i get an error.

Here's my code so far:

```
mand_circ = (16, 3, 19, 3, 4, 9, 3, 9, 4, 10, 47, 2, 39, 9, 18, 6, 5, 9, 5, 6, 2, 2)

votacoes = ((0, 15729, 220408, 1297, 0, 3040, 993, 0, 1354, 1046, 0, 3284, 99652, 19327, 0), (0, 19000, 23173, 255, 0, 532, 201, 0, 306, 232, 0, 1980, 22307, 3890, 0), (0, 23731, 244971, 1959, 0, 2710, 1465, 0, 1094, 1114, 0, 4264, 159476, 20488, 0), (0, 1956, 47716, 282, 0, 0, 175, 0, 165, 247, 0, 417, 19728, 1732, 0), (0, 5384, 52325, 403, 0, 770, 543, 0, 428, 0, 0, 1454, 38317, 4609, 0), (0, 14138, 113419, 662, 0, 2535, 600, 0, 591, 557, 0, 2014, 66199, 13034, 0), (0, 18967, 31260, 237, 0, 649, 216, 0, 168, 207, 0, 1810, 25010, 4225, 0),(0, 17255, 99745, 2076, 0, 3285, 0, 0, 1069, 700, 0, 3160, 46082, 16347, 0), (0, 3299, 53450, 251, 0, 520, 199, 0, 178, 191, 0, 755, 26263, 3114, 0), (0, 12351, 148762, 977, 0, 3029, 633, 0, 595, 453, 0, 2502, 51518, 0, 0), (0, 111661, 560365, 4135, 0, 16913, 2410, 0, 5897, 4270, 0, 14419, 322034, 66874, 0), (0, 7910, 26257, 176, 0, 333, 162, 0, 151, 135, 0, 1031, 19963, 2753, 0), (0, 61832, 488402, 2413, 0, 9072, 3386, 0, 1551, 1525, 0, 9640, 318113, 51002, 0), (0, 21347, 118028, 1454, 0, 2220, 692, 0, 832, 726, 0, 3413, 61194, 13712, 0), (0, 82159, 156444, 1682, 0, 6282, 1133, 0, 1595, 847, 0, 0, 112764, 29667, 0), (0, 6648, 76961, 384, 0, 926, 0, 0, 213, 331, 0, 1473, 35327, 5928, 0), (0, 3656, 71840, 304, 0, 617, 254, 0, 147, 574, 0, 675, 34825, 2784, 0), (0, 5810, 123184, 696, 0, 1229, 465, 0, 266, 626, 0, 1456, 54107, 5786, 0), (0, 2288, 53518, 314, 0, 756, 293, 0, 219, 271, 0, 669, 23189, 3965, 0), (0, 5096, 87597, 2560, 0, 2385, 2992, 0, 617, 538, 0, 1967, 20360, 5568, 0), (0, 803, 6306, 101, 0, 192, 83, 0, 48, 50, 0, 132, 7205, 602, 0), (0, 127, 8938, 87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 47, 0,52, 2714, 165, 0))

def mandatos(n, t):
    lst_votos = list(t)
    lst = []
    for e in t:
        lst = lst + [0]    

    lst_mand = list(n)
    lstm = []
    for i in n:
        lstm = lstm + [0]        

    while n > 0:
        maior = lst_votos[0]
        for i in range(0, len(lst_votos)):
            if lst_votos[i] > maior:
                maior = lst_votos[i]         

        for j in range(0, len(lst_votos)):
            if maior == lst_votos[j]:
                p = j     

        lst[p] = lst[p] + 1
        lst_votos = lst_votos[:p] + [(lst_votos[p] * lst[p]) / (lst[p] +1)] + lst_votos[p+1:]

        n = n - 1

    return tuple(lst)
```

The variable mand_circ goes to position n, and votacoes goes to position t when i call the function.

The error i get is:
`builtins.TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() > int()
line 43, in <module>    while n > 0:`

I've tried to convert n to int, but i failed every time.
The worst is that i think this is not the only error in here, but i can't get pass this point..... some help please...

Comment: If you are calling the function with `mand_circ` as the `n` parameter then `n` is a tuple. What int is `n` supposed to be if you pass in a tuple?

Comment: mand_circ is a tuple and votacoes is a tuple of tuples. for each number in mand_circ i want to get the same position tuple in votacoes.

Comment: For exemple, for the first position in `mand_circ`, wich is 16, i want to get the first tuple in `votacoes`, to call the function `mandatos` like this:

`mandatos(16, (0, 15729, 220408, 1297, 0, 3040, 993, 0, 1354, 1046, 0, 3284, 99652, 19327, 0))`